# SQLAutoCode - error when attempting to generate schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to auto generate a schema for use in SQLalchemy, I'm using sqlautocode to do this, I use the following command

```
D:~ admin$ sqlautocode mysql://'user':"pass"@xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/db_name -o tables.py
```

but I keep getting the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sqlautocode", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('sqlautocode==0.7', 'console_scripts', 'sqlautocode')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
  return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2354, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2060, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlautocode/main.py", line 4, in <module>
from declarative import ModelFactory
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlautocode/declarative.py", line 17, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import _deferred_relation as _deferred_relationship
ImportError: cannot import name _deferred_relation
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlautocode

Comment: I got this working by downgrading to SA 0.6.8, not sure if this module now works with SA...

Comment: There are a couple of proposed fixes...
https://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/issues/detail?id=42
https://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/issues/detail?id=27

Comment: Even after fixing sqlautocode with @tbischel's links, I found [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen) to work better

Comment: @Pakman your link should be the accepted answer here

Answer (score 3):

Use [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen) instead:

`D:~ admin$ sqlacodegen mysql://'users':"pass"@xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/db_name --outfile tables.py`

Answer (score 0):

this is because you sqlalchemy version is above 07.
find declarative.py in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlautocode

change from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import _deferred_relationship  To
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry import _deferred_relationship

this work in my work.